# is it safe to cast a pointer to a template class invocation to a different invocation of the same template?

Tags: c++, templates, casting

the motivation here is to build up a library of functions that operate on data without knowing anything about the data. in the example below, test_me invokes the widget template with the real data type (int). and derives a widget that acts on the passed data. then passes them to a library routine that passes the data pointer to the virtual act method.

```
template <class T>
class widget
{
public:
  widget() {}
  virtual ~widget() {}
  virtual void act( T *p ) = 0;
};
class int_widget : public widget<int>
{
public:
  int_widget() : widget() {}
  virtual ~int_widget() {}
  virtual void act( int *p ) {
    printf( "*p=%d\n", *p );
  }
};
void pass_to( void *data, widget<void> *wvp )
{
  wvp->act( data );
}
void test_me()
{
  // we want to pass 42 to an int_widget...
  int i = 42;
  int_widget iw;
  // is this a safe way to do it?
  pass_to( (void *) &i, (widget<void> *) &iw );
}
```

obviously the consumer of the library is accepting responsibility for ensuring all of the widgets can correctly interpret the data they are given.

this works if the compiler lays out the vtables for the various invocations of widget in exactly the same way. and there are no issues casting pointers to the actual data.

the questions are: did i miss any conditions other than the above?
and for all practical purposes, are the above assumptions valid?

Comment: They're unrelated types (that they source from the same template is irrelevant). And it isn't needed anyway; make `pass_to` a template function.

Comment: heh. good suggestion. unfortunately in the real application, we'd like to pass an array of widget<void>* to pass_to. which would call act on each one in sequence.

Answer (score 5):

No it is not safe. Different template instantiations are fundamentally different types.

A cast from one such type to another via void* is undefined behaviour.

Comment: there are two casts in the example. which are unsafe? the cast of the data from int* to void*? or the cast from widget<int>* to widget<void>*? or both? ;->